# Running a specific php file from a menu or button

Tags: php

I have a number of small php files; one to add a record to a table, one to edit a record in a table, and one to display all the records in the table.

I can run each one independently. But need a program with a menu or buttons that I click on to load and run the specified file.

I just need a simple solution, but I'm not sure how this is dome as I'm new to php.

Please can you point me in the correct direction.

Thank you.

Comment: you can use jQuery also for this. Just write `window.location = 'yourphpfile.php';` in button.

Comment: So what is the problem here, you don’t know how basic links work in HTML? `<a href="somescript.php">call somescript.php</a>` …?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. As I said I am new to PHP so wasn't sure how to start. I have previously added links in HTML. What I have below looks like a link in a button.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>  
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
    <h2>Training Module</h2>
    <button type="button"> <a href="http://localhost:8080/trainingmodule/CreateEmployeeTable.php">Create Empty Employee Table</a></button>
    <button type="button"> <a href="http://localhost:8080/trainingmodule/AddEmployee.php">Add Employee</a></button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```